# Asp.net MVC 2 - Returned Json object not being picked up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, simplemodal, json.net

**Update: I've removed the datatype="html" completely and hoping the return value will always get evaluated - but right now nothing happens.**

**I've also added the code that calls the "openModal" function. It is in the LogOn UserControl contained in the Site.Master.  Hope this clears up a few things**

**It seems like from the Controller is not returning the json object back to the ajax caller, something is lost somewhere - i am never hitting that break point..it skips it entirely**

I have a simple modal for logins, so i call the LogOn Action like this:

```
<div id="logonForm">         
     <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "logonForm"})) { %>
          //my login form
<% } %>
</div>
```

And the Action looks like this:

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
       //success login
       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
           return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("Index", "Home") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       else
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                               
    }
```

At this point it retursthe new Json object with the Url to the User Control (in Site.Master), to the javascript here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModel() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: '/Account/LogOn',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
                //  async: true,  
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    if (typeof result == 'string') {
                        $.modal(result, {
                            closeHTML: "",
                            containerId: "login-container",
                            overlayClose: true
                        });
                    }
                    else if (result.Url) {
                        debugger;
                        window.location.href = result.Url;
                    }
                }
            });

        }

</script>

<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
        Welcome <b><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></b>!
         <%: Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account") %>         
<% } else { %> 
         <a href="javascript:openModel()">Log In</a> 
<% } %>
```

...but the javacript never catches it..i cannot see whats in the "result", the screen renders an  "{Url: /}" - just weird behavior

What am i missing? the debugger; break is triggered when i first click the link, but when i try to submit form, it goes thru the LogOn Controller - tries to return the json object, but never goes back to the javascript

Thanks much

Comment: Where does `openModel` get called from ?

Comment: `dataType: "html",` this line seems wrong... shouldn't it be `dataType: "json",`

Comment: This is a follow up question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293765/asp-net-mvc-login-modal-problems-redirect-goes-to-modal/4293904

Comment: @Josiah - it is - not sure what the convention is - should i link the 2 questions?

Comment: Have you tried the `appendTo:'form'` option for the SimpleModal call?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery will not treat the call as returning json, because you have told it the call is returning `html`. You need to change your `dataType` to `json`.

However it isn't clear where you expect `openModel` to be called from. The code as it is will use the Microsoft AJAX code and insert the returned data into the page, which is why you are seeing your json appear on the page.

Comment: i updated the original post to include where its coming from - its being called by the UserControl that renders the Login link (in Site.Master)

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: "html",` should be be `dataType: "json",`, and this should solve the problem.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Actually, I think that *is* the answer. I have edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the submit click to call your custom jQuery ajax function. Right now it will use the Microsoft ajax. This is why your ajax function never gets called.

Do something like:

```
$('form').unbind('submit').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({ type:'post', url: '/Account/LogOn', data: $(this).serialize(), 
       success: function(){
           if (result.Url)
               window.location.href = result.Url;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well jQuery will never trigger the `success` callback, since you specified `dataType: "html",`, so it will wait for an `text/html` response, but you're sending JSON.

You need to use `"json"` as the dataType.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It will trigger (you can see in the question this is happening, it's displaying the JSON), it'll just treat it as a string, never parsing the JSON.

Comment: @Nick Indeed, missed that, a bit more formatting would have helped to state that clear, still seems like a bug to me, silently fails here should throw an error in case something different gets returned than was requested :/

Comment: @Ivo - Not a bug...you're telling it "hey no matter what, treat it as html"...exactly what jQuery is doing here :)

Comment: @Nick "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server." so I **expect** html in this case, but header tells jQuery something different, that breaks my expectation, anyways.

Comment: @Ivo - not sure who downvoted - but you're overriding jQuery here...if you leave off the option it'll choose based on the header, I think that's absolutely the right behavior - think of it this way, if it was completely automatic....why have an option at all?

Comment: You have the option in case you aren't in full control of what the server returns. If the server returns the wrong headers/mimetype then with the option you get to override jQuery's auto detection code to resolve it.